# Self Service password reset for AD users

Tags: azure, active-directory

How can I configure Self service password reset for AD users(not Azure Active Directory) in Azure? So that when the password expires the user can themselves reset the password instead of asking the administrator/admin to go to portal and reset their password.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/tutorial-enable-sspr - Did you happen to check this  ?

Comment: Yes, I did check it and it is not helpful in my case as I already told that I want SSPR for active directory not for azure active directory as for that I will need to have global administrator right, which are not given in client subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at my company, we are facing the same dilemma our users thankfully have domain-joined laptops and just connect to VPN and change their passwords that way (not that's any use for you). You can check out a couple of open-sourced projects for hosting a website that users can go to and reset their password. You can also get a higher-tier subscription and allow them to reset their password via O365 as well.

https://github.com/mprahl/ADReset